# How to plot graph with certain requirement of choosing of x-axis in data table in R?

Tags: r

I have a data frame as following:

```
>str(df)
'data.frame':   22673 obs. of  6 variables:

$ V1  : Factor w/ 39 levels "2015-02-09","2015-02-09 ",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
$ V2  : Factor w/ 10465 levels "00:48:26","01:49:26",..: 3949 3956 3964 3985 4196 4254 4262 4268 4275 4309 ...
$ V3  : Factor w/ 3 levels "Admin","AmbassadorSchoolPlayer",..: 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 1 3 ...
$ V4  : Factor w/ 104 levels "1builder1","22mAsgarfus",..: 77 77 57 77 48 48 48 48 6 77 ...
$ V5  : Factor w/ 8580 levels ""," - -?"," - 14 1",..: 2306 874 7433 3650 2306 2306 3364 6501 3257 2306 ...
```

`df$V4` is the user_name, and I'd like to plot the graph which takes `df$V1` as x-axis, `df$V4` as y-axis. But given the number of user is too big, I 'd like to choose the ones(user-name) who appear for more than a threshold times, let's say, 10, in the data frame. How can I do it? I am quite new to R, and I have read several article introducing ggplot2, but did not find the answer. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the table function

```
count <- table(df$V4)
```

subset which usernames with more than 10 entries

```
some_usernames <- names(count[count>10])
```

then subset your dataframe

```
df_subset <- df[df$V4 %in% some_usernames, ]
```

then use ggplot2 or base graphics to do what you want. Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for your help! It works! It's so kind of you!